# Elastic div between two fixed height/width divs

Tags: html, css

There are some answers to a similar question already, but this one has a twist.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 grey">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="info">(i)</div>
            <div class="text"><div class="labeled">This is a long text</div></div>
            <div class="icon">[$]</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 green">
        Content
    </div>

</div>
```

So I need three divs, aligned in one line at all conditions - info, text, icon - with two divs on the sides having fixed h/w, and one in the middle taking only as much space, as

- either it needs, and not more
- or is available for it, cutting the context with overflow:hidden

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L7tmt5w1/3/

Here are my mad skills in sketching ideas https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ksml.jpg

For those, who want to feel my pain, you may also try re-ordering the divs - text, icon, info - when the screen size goes mobile (bootstrap's col-xs-)

Comment: Could you accept one of the answers?

Comment: Kyle's answer was the closest, although I had to use jQuery to set the width - and thus force overflow: hidden - explicitely. I've voted it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display: table-cell;` method for this situation:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.info {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #005ea8;
    color: #fff;
}

.icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #eb690b;
    color: #fff;
}

.text {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: auto;
}
```

This mimics the table display properties and keeps all the children of `.wrapper` inline and the middle one "elastic" as it has no defined width. You can also remove the floats.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7tmt5w1/7/

Comment: Almost good! Except for it not cutting off the text. white-space: nowrap on .text haven't helped yet.

Comment: You can of course wrap the text in a span element with display: block; to control the width of it ;)

Comment: Doesn't help :/ That, or I am tweaking it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this solution will help you [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vsIem)

```
<aside class="panel">
    ...
</aside>
<div class="content">
    ...
</div>


.content {
    overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px  solid;
}
.panel {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
  border: 1px  solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/L7tmt5w1/3/

Remember: If you want to float an element to the right, it must be the first element. For example:

```
<div style="float:right"></div>
<div style="float:left"></div>
```

AND `DIV`'s are already block elements, so you don't have to add `display:block` to a `DIV`-element

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you want: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7tmt5w1/6/)

if not content on "text" no div... if too much content it's hidden

(but you can add

```
overflow:auto
```

to the text div for scroll bars

Comment: I was not SURE if this is what he wanted... but I think it is. however people downgrading answers as fast as you without even checking my answer are quite... nvm. All I want is to help people as often people around has helped me. People like You just make me want to quit using stackoverflow.

Comment: Your answer makes it seem like you didn't read the question, plus it contains some pretty horrible CSS. So take the downvote as you will. I stand by it.

Comment: The CSS was "horrible" right from the start of the original question, so no one to blame here...